# Android - Preventing TalkBack to read the application Name and current Orientation

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Problem is I am using TTS to read a long string message when my activity is launched, but TalkBack automatically reads the application name in the middle of it and cuts the long string and is very annoying.

I would like to disable the TalkBack read the Application name every time an activity is launched. Removing its android:label attribute is not a viable solution as the application is controlled by someone else and I have no control over it.

So, Is there any API that I could call to prevent the TalkBack feature from reading the application name when an application is launched?

Any Help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,
Ashok

Comment: When you say "the application is controlled by someone else," are you still able to add code in Activity.onCreate()?

Comment: Yes. I have control over the Activity, but not over the the manifest file of the application.

Answer (score 9):

A solution would be to override dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent() in Activity to return true. This will prevent Talkback from announcing activity label.

Comment: You have to return false not true. At least this prevent Talkback from announcing my application name

Answer (score 7):

You should add this to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mobile.myapp.test"
            android:label="About"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Leave android:label empty if you don't want TalkBack to read activity name.

Comment: When leaving the label empty the Application name is used.

Comment: The label should have been a spacebar android:label=" ". This approach worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

But  this line in `onCreate` of Launcher `Activity`

**Kotlin**:

```
ViewCompat.setImportantForAccessibility(window.decorView,
ViewCompat.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO)
```

**Java**:

```
ViewCompat.setImportantForAccessibility(getWindow().getDecorView(),
ViewCompat.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> So, Is there any API that I could call to prevent the TalkBack feature from reading the application name when an application is launched?

Not that I am aware of.

> Problem is I am using TTS to read a long string message when my activity is launched, but TalkBack automatically reads the application name in the middle of it and cuts the long string and is very annoying.

Then delay your "long string message" a bit, to give time for TalkBack to do its standard announcements.

Comment: I have done exactly the same, but I was wondering if there is any other way to handle this issue. Thanks for your reply. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

For Preventing TalkBack to read the application Name every time you switch activity is to set a name (label) of the Activity in Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".pavlos.myActivity"
        android:label="Pavlos Activity" />
```

Adding `android:name=""` to Manifest will stop TalkBack announcing the name of the App every time you switch Activities.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the app name was **mispronounced** by TalkBack.
I fixed that by correcting the string name in strings.xml file.

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">Your App Name</string>
</resources>
```

What I previously had there was a name without spaces.

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">YourAppName</string>
</resources>
```

I hope that if you just left it empty or with empty space, you would get your desired effect.